# Typescript: how to extract type from union of Boxes?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some Box type and Union which includes both boxed values and raw values. How can i extract boxed types?

```
class Box<T> {};
type United = Box<number> | Box<string> | boolean;
type Unboxed<T> = ???
type ExtractUnited = Unboxed<United>; // number | string
```

Comment: @KevinJohnson how would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to use `T` inside your `Box` class:

```
class Box<T> {
    constructor(public value: T) {}
};
```

Second, declare `Unboxed<T>` as:

```
type Unboxed<T> = T extends Box<infer U> ? U : never;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2APAPAFQHzQN4Chr+mHgDsIAXAJwFdgz4KAKAByoCMQBLYaANzBCoBTAFzRUASmwBfHFIDcOMgE8mg6AFViHMoIAm0ALxwkyYlQC2rQRUwAfYynIUOxAOZ3orePBCCwxBWVVDWIvRD00TCNUaEFEHWJdGAQUFwAzaw1MAH4NaFFiQR5rQJU1AFF4ijBaTW09QxCwiLqdXXQ5aAB6LugzS0z7JxdXIA)